# Automatic configure wordpress IP on EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed a LAMP server on an EC2 instance. Then I created an AMI so that I can easily spin up instances in the future.

Today I went back to spin up one such instance, and to my surprise the IP in the configuration is wrong. Basically when I first installed the LAMP server, Wordpress detected the IP and configured accordingly. Now on the instance that I launched today the IP is different, but the configuration for the previous IP is still there.

Now, I know how to change Wordpress IP. My question is: How can I make this step automatic when I launch an EC2 instance from an AMI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Instance Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) will give you  a lot of information about the current EC2 instace. You can use that + some hand-crafted shell scripts which will be triggered on boot to update configuration.

An alternative solution is to use some configuration management tool (Chef, Ansible ... ). To help you configure the application.